# Using Cursor to loop through a Table variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a parameter in the Stored Prod which gets some data in the format

```
1/1/2018-2/1/2018,2/1/2018-3/1/2018,3/1/2018-4/1/2018,4/1/2018-5/1/2018,5/1/2018-6/1/2018,6/1/2018-7/1/2018,7/1/2018-8/1/2018,8/1/2018-9/1/2018,9/1/2018-10/1/2018,
10/1/2018-11/1/2018,11/1/2018-12/1/2018,12/1/2018-12/31/2018
```

I have a function which splits the data based on , character and stores it in a table variable as shown below

```
declare @SPlitDates table(ItemNumber int,Item nvarchar(max))
insert into @SPlitDates
select * from dbo.SPlitFunction(@RequestData, ',')
```

After this I have to perform certain operations on the data range so I use cursors to loop through the temp table as shown below

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Item FROM @SPlitDates order by ItemNumber
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @monthStart
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
--Some operation
End
```

The max data points that I will get in the temp table is the date range for 12 months.

My question is that could I be using something else apart from Cursors to improve performance or it doesn't matter when the dataset is really this small.

Thanks

Comment: You probably could, but what is inside the cursor, the `--Some operation`, that part will be important for possible rewrites. Also using a temporary table instead of a table variable can help speed things up when rewriting.

Comment: that some operation is where I have some temp tables getting data based on  the cursors table variable date range

Comment: Do you need to process this data row by row?

Comment: Skip the cursor and use temporary tables with all the proper records at the same time instead of going 1 by 1. The only reason you should keep the cursor is for executing procedures that can't work with sets (like sending emails or executing cmd commands).

Answer (score 2):

If possible, just treat this as a set and consider if you can rewrite the `--Some operation` as a single batch.

It may require you to get smart with joins to other tables based on the date ranges - or perhaps you could split the date range further into StartDate and EndDate columns before doing your additional processing which might help with joins

Answer (score 1):

The higher the number of rows, the worse a cursor is for you.  If you aren't ever dealing with a lot of rows, cursor is fine.  However, if you are dealing with large amounts of rows OR you WILL BE down the road, you should explore set-based code.  I'm sure it won't be exactly right because I don't have all the information but compare the two below as rough example:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Item FROM @SPlitDates order by ItemNumber
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @monthStart
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
--Some operation

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @monthStart -- next item
End
-- housekeeping
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

--This would be close to a set-based operation of that cursor--

Insert @monthStart(Item)
SELECT Item 
--CASE EXPRESSION(s)--
FROM @SPlitDates
order by ItemNumber
```

Comment: Also these are good free classes that walk through examples of converting cursors to set-based operations.  

https://www.brentozar.com/training/t-sql-level/8-replacing-cursors-part-1-6m/

Answer (score -1):

You can using like this

```
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT)
insert into @myTableVariable values(1),(2),(3)
declare @id  INT = 0;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM @myTableVariable
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    print   CONCAT(' Id  =', CAST(@id AS NVARCHAR(100)))
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id -- next item
End
```